# Do improper integrals like $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f$ converge if $xf(x)\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

My teacher assumes without proof in his notes that, given a rational function $R(x)$, the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} R(x)dx$ converges if $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty} xR(x) = 0$. He then proceeds to explain the [Estimation lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma), that is a very similar result.

However it is unclear for me whether this fact is true, and if it is bidirectional (i.e. if $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} R(x)dx$ converges then $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty} xR(x) = 0$) and holds true even for non-rational functions

Comment: Presumably your rational function has no poles. Then the result is true, and bidirectional. One cannot expect anything similar for general functions. The standard example is $\frac{1}{x\log x}$. This needs to be fixed up if you want the interval to be $(-\infty,\infty)$, easy to do.  Just let $f(x)=1/(|x|\log(|x|))$ for $|x|\ge 2$, and anything nice between $-2$ and $2$.

Comment: In general the function you're integrating can have no limit at infinity. The same holds for $x f$. Take for example comb function http://d.pr/i/ElNd+ or if you want to deal with formulas, take sth like $f(x) = x^2 \exp (-x^8 \sin^2 (40x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot extend the result to general functions. For example, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|\log(|x|)}$ if $|x|\ge 2$, and let $f(x)=f(2)$ for $-2 \lt x\lt 2$.

Then $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x)=\lim_{x\to -\infty} xf(x)=0$, but the improper integral does not converge.

The result does hold, *bidirectionally*, for rational functions whose denominator vanishes nowhere. It is essentially obvious, though writing out the proof is typographically unpleasant. For a rational function $R(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials with $Q(x)$ nowhere $0$ (and $P$ not identically $0$), there is convergence iff $\deg(Q)\ge 2+\deg(P)$. This is precisely the condition for $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} xR(x)$ to be $0$.  The reason is basically that degrees can only take on integer values.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx $ where $P,Q$ are polynomials and $x$ is a real variable. This converges absolutely if $\deg(P) \leq \deg(Q) -2.$ To evaluate this family of integrals, we consider $\displaystyle \int_C \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} dz$ where $C$ is the standard semi-circular contour in the upper half plane with radius $R.$ The Estimation Lemma yields that the contribution from the arc is $\mathcal{O}(1/R)$ as $R\to\infty.$

Hence $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx = 2\pi i \sum \text{ Residues of P/Q in the upper half plane }.$$

When $\deg(P)=\deg(Q)-1$ this same calculation holds true, but now the calculated value does not represent $\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx$ ; that integral does not exist because we get different values if the upper and lower limits tend to infinity in different ways. What does exist (and we calculated) is the *Cauchy Principle Value*: $$\text{ C.P.V } \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx = \lim_{R\to \infty} \int^R_R \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx.$$

If $Q$ has a simple zero at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ our calculation still returns a value we can make sense of, another Cauchy principle value: $$\text{ C.P.V} \int^b_a \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int^{x_0+\epsilon}_a\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx + \int^b_{x_0-\epsilon}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx.$$

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I chose the other answer because it answers well just what I have asked, so it is good for a reference, but your answer helps me to understand better what I'm studying

Comment: @Cauchy Good to hear, I had hoped that it would.